How to make IsManaged to false for realm objects?
I have a relam class which inherits realm object. I am able to query the Atlas but when JSON is assigned to class by default its managed. I want to make that object unmanaged. Currently its done by converting it to JSON then making IsManaged to false then deseraising it to object. But this is taking more time. I am looking for solution which can perform better

The question is a bit unclear. If you want an object to not be a Realm object omit the : Object in it's model definition. Likewise, you can omit properties from being managed by omitting the @Persisted on the property definition line. JSON is assigned to class by default is unclear though - not sure what that means. Do you some example that can be included in the question? Also clarifying what's being asked would help us.
